# TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) why i am getting this error?

Tags: python

```
import datetime

tarih = input('aracınız hangi tarihte trafiğe çıktı (2019/8/9): ')
tarih = tarih.split('/')
trafigeCikis = datetime.datetime(int(tarih[0],tarih[1],tarih[2]))
simdi = datetime.datetime.now()
fark = simdi - trafigeCikis
days = fark.days
if days<=365:
    print('1. servis aralığı')
elif days>365 and days<=365*2:
    print('2. servis aralığı')
elif days>365*2 and days<=365*3:
    print('3. servis aralığı.')
else:
    print('hatalı giriş yaptınız.')
```

TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
why i am getting this error?

Comment: Because you are giving 3 arguments to the int function when it can take at most 2 arguments

Comment: how can i solve

Answer (score 1):

replace to `int(tarih[0]), int(tarih[1]), int(tarih[2])`. or `*map(int, tarih)`

Comment: by the way you can compare like this: `365 < days <= 365*2`